# Would you recommend the book "Philosophical devices: Evidence, Probability, Possibility and Sets" by David Papineau?

Tags: logic, reference-request

Would you recommend the book "Philosophical devices: Evidence, Probability, Possibility and Sets"?
I am not familiar with the author, David Papineau, and would like to ask for an opinion regarding how it is written and especially regarding the content. The table of contents can be found [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199651736). I'm not an expert and, even if you haven't read it, could you tell me if, compared to the topics covered, it is worth buying? Thanks!

Comment: In case the link doesn't work: https://www.amazon.com/Philosophical-Devices-Proofs-Probabilities-Possibilities-dp-0199651736/dp/0199651736/ref=mt_other?_encoding=UTF8&me=&qid=

Comment: I would absolutely do recommend this book.

Comment: Also : The math you need to do philosophy. But Papineau's book should be read in priority.

Comment: If you aim at studying philosophy at university in an English speaking country where analytic philosophy is predominant, Papineau's book is really the right place to start.

Answer (score 1):

David Papineau is a well-respected and known philosopher who predominantly deals with the philosophy of mind. His position is close to [the identity theory](http://consc.net/books/tcm/papineau-response.html).

The aforementioned book generally [scores very good reviews](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13689443-philosophical-devices). So, I would say go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are looking for. If you have some logic under your belt it will take you deeper into the subject. If this is your first foray into the subject, you might want to look elsewhere. I’ve been working with books that are old and out of print, and don’t know what is currently available.

Comment: Thanks! What book would you recommend as a first approach to logic, especially oriented toward philosophy?

Answer (score 0):

Like I said, most of my books are old and no longer in print. I did pick up a copy of “A Concise Introduction to Logic” 10th edition by Patrick J. Hurley published in 2008 at a used bookstore. It looks to be geared towards philosophical logic but I haven’t read enough to say it is “good”. It looks to be what I’m looking for.